# how to prepend xml namespace in element during query?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

With the following

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Test nvarchar(50), Location_ID uniqueidentifier);
INSERT INTO @t (Test,Location_ID ) 
SELECT Test,Location_ID 
from
dbo.TEST;
DECLARE @xml XML
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
'typens:GPCodedValueDomain2' as type,
'http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0' as typens, 
'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/' AS xs, 
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi )
SELECT @xml = 
    (
    SELECT 
    'typens:CodedValue' AS "@xsi:type", 
    TEST AS "Name", Location_ID  AS "Code"
    FROM @t 
    order by Location_ID
    FOR XML PATH
    ('CodedValue'), ROOT
    ('GPCodedValueDomain2'),TYPE
    )
SELECT @xml
```

it outputs

```
<GPCodedValueDomain2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0" xmlns:type="typens:GPCodedValueDomain2">
  <CodedValue xsi:type="typens:CodedValue">
    <Name>test update</Name>
    <Code>B59D3BEB-CBCE-E111-B5B0-002564D275D1</Code>
  </CodedValue>
  <CodedValue xsi:type="typens:CodedValue">
    <Name>test update</Name>
    <Code>B69D3BEB-CBCE-E111-B5B0-002564D275D1</Code>
  </CodedValue>
  <CodedValue xsi:type="typens:CodedValue">
    <Name>test update</Name>
    <Code>B79D3BEB-CBCE-E111-B5B0-002564D275D1</Code>
  </CodedValue>
</GPCodedValueDomain2>
```

I've been trying different iterations of namespace definition for hours, all fail. I'm looking for the output to be:

```
<GPCodedValueDomain2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0" xmlns:type="typens:GPCodedValueDomain2">
  <CodedValue xsi:type="typens:CodedValue">
    <Name>test update</Name>
    <Code xsi:type="xs:string">B59D3BEB-CBCE-E111-B5B0-002564D275D1</Code>
  </CodedValue>
  <CodedValue xsi:type="typens:CodedValue">
    <Name>test update</Name>
    <Code xsi:type="xs:string">B69D3BEB-CBCE-E111-B5B0-002564D275D1</Code>
  </CodedValue>
  <CodedValue xsi:type="typens:CodedValue">
    <Name>test update</Name>
    <Code xsi:type="xs:string">B79D3BEB-CBCE-E111-B5B0-002564D275D1</Code>
  </CodedValue>
</GPCodedValueDomain2>
```

Any thoughts on how to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a SQL Server user, but I wonder if you are really providing a schema document that defines a type named `string` in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/`.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with binding the prefix `xs` to the namespace whose name is the URI of the HTML 4 spec.  But several things make me wonder whether you have defined your problem clearly enough.

- The HTML 4 spec doesn't define a datatype named `string`; unless you are doing something very unusual in a schema document not shown here, `xs:string` is not going to denote a known type.
- You appear to be binding the namespace prefix `type` to the namespace URI `typens:GPCodedValueDomain2`.  That namespace prefix doesn't seem to be used anywhere else, so it's not clear what purpose it's serving.  The fact that the URI scheme `typens` used in that namespace name is also a namespace prefix defined elsewhere in your query suggests that you are either confused about namespace and namespace prefixes, or else that you are doing something extremely subtle and devious.  In the latter case, you surely don't need help from Stack Overflow.
- You want `xsi:type` attributes on the `CodedValue` and `Code` elements in your output.  Your query succeeds in putting the attribute on the first, by specifying `SELECT 'typens:CodedValue' AS "@xsi:type", ...` for it.  But there is no analogous construct for the `Code` element. Why not?

Comment: The xml is from a column which is initially populated by an application, which performs a good portion of app configuration via xml, of which the posted xml is an example of one. I appreciate your comments, but I'm not doing anything "devious" nor have I invented my own namespace. I'm simply working with what the application outputs, and what it needs in order to read the xml and present the elements/nodes to the applications.